# struts2 TreeMap: keys with spaces not appearing in action

Tags: struts2, treemap, xwork

**JSP Code:**

```
   <s:iterator value="#currentRequisitionGroup.plFldWrap.allPFields" var="pMap" status="hStatus">
    <s:iterator value="#pMap.value.paramMdlList" var="paramModel" status="fStat">
    <li>
     <label>
        <s:property value="#paramModel.parameterName" />

     </label> 
    <s:set var="cEdit" value="%{#paramModel.isEditable}"> </s:set>  

    <s:if test="%{#cEdit == true}">
        <s:textfield id="paramId_%{#paramModel.parameterId}" name="rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[%     {#cGStat.index}].plFldWrap.allPFields['%{(#pMap.key)}'].paramMdlList[%{#fStat.index}].prmValue"/>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
         <s:textfield id="paramId_%{#paramModel.parameterId}" name="rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[%  {#cGStat.index}].plFldWrap.allPFields['%{(#pMap.key)}'].paramMdlList[%{#fStat.index}].prmValue" readonly="true"/>
    </s:else>    



</li> 
<s:hidden id="prmId_%{#paramModel.parameterId}" name="rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[%{#cGStat.index}].plFldWrap.allPFields['%{(#pMap.key)}'].paramMdlList[%{#fStat.index}].parameterId"></s:hidden> 
<s:hidden id="paramName_%{#paramModel.parameterId}" name="rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[%{#cGStat.index}].plFldWrap.allPFields['%{(#pMap.key)}'].paramMdlList[%{#fStat.index}].parameterName"></s:hidden>
<s:hidden id="pGId_%{#paramModel.parameterId}"  name="rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[%{#cGStat.index}].plFldWrap.allPFields['%{(#pMap.key)}'].paramMdlList[%{#fStat.index}].parameterGroupId"></s:hidden> 
<s:hidden id="seqNo_%{#paramModel.parameterId}" name="rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[%{#cGStat.index}].plFldWrap.allPFields['%{(#pMap.key)}'].paramMdlList[%{#fStat.index}].sequenceNumber"></s:hidden>

</s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
```

The problem is that some values do not appear in action.
Investigation till now indicates that, if the corresponding html *input has space* in the key of allPFields, that value doesn't appear in action.
     `<input id="prmId_30" type="hidden" value="30" 
      name="rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[1].plFldWrap.allPFields['Emp System'].paramMdlList[0].parameterId">`

However, if the corresponding html input has *no space in the key* of allPFields, that value appears in action.
   `<input id="prmId_46" type="hidden" value="30"   name="rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[1].plFldWrap.allPFields['Emp'].paramMdlList[0].parameterId">`

**Here is what the logs say:**
`xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor - Parameter [rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[1].plFldWrap.allPFields['Emp System'].paramMdlList[0].parameterId] **didn't match acceptedPattern pattern!**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because white spaces are not accepted in parameter names. You can change `acceptParamNames` parameter of the `ParametersInterceptor`, BUT as the documentation states

> acceptParamNames - a comma delimited list of regular expressions to describe a whitelist of accepted parameter names. **Don't change the default unless you know what you are doing in terms of security implications**

So I suggest you to get rid of white spaces in parameters names.

Comment: Thank you Aleksandr M. Used `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
.deleteWhitespace(inputStr)` and it worked.